# Create a range from offsets

Tags: vba, excel

I need to select a range in relation to a certain cell.

This is what i have so far - the user double clicks a cell:

```
Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
```

The cell the user clicked is then available in `Target` as a `Range`.

I then need to select a new `Range` relative to the position of `Target`. I have tried the code below:

```
dataSheet.Range(Target.Offset(2, 2)), Target.Offset(15, bHeight)).Select
```

I've tried a lot of different ways from reading other people posts using `.Cells`, `.Address`, but can't seem to get it to work. I think I'm getting the data types mixed up? Any Ideas?

Comment: What is `bHeight` ?

Comment: @RobinMackenzie an integer variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine `Offset` and `Resize` to achieve your outcome. First use `Offset` to get the displacement from `Target` and then `Resize` to increase the range to the required number of rows and columns. Here is example code:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

    Dim rngNew As Range
    Dim bHeight As Integer

    bHeight = 3
    Set rngNew = Target.Offset(2, 2).Resize(13, bHeight)

    rngNew.Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Should `Cancel` be set to `True` ??

Comment: @Gary'sStudent - good point - doesn't seem to make a difference to the behaviour for this small test case. Could quite well make a difference to the OP depending on their set-up.